# Java program for prime factorization prints too much

Tags: java, primes, prime-factoring, factorization

I was given a problem to solve at school, which goes like this:

> Write a program that reads a positive integer greater than 1 and then prints out the prime factors of the number in increasing order. If the number is a prime, print out that number followed by a statement saying that it is a prime, as shown in one of the examples.

So then I wrote this program and it has expected behaviour when I put in an actual prime. If I put in 97, the output will be "97 is a prime number." as supposed.

But when I input 120 it prints "2 2 2 3 5 is a prime number" where expected behaviour would be only to print the numbers and not the "is a prime number" text.

Method that checks if the input number is a prime, and if so, prints the factors of it:

```
public static void primeFactors(int n) {

    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(2 + " ");
        n = n/2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i = i+2) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            n = n/i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 2) {
        System.out.print(n + " is a prime number.");
    }
}
```

Main method:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = reader.nextInt();
    primeFactors(n);
}
```

So I'd like some help figuring out how to make it so that the "is a prime number." ending is ONLY printed when the entered number specifically is a prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the parameter n into a variable to keep it.

```
int input = n;
```

Then in the end change your output to the following:

```
if (n > 2) {
    System.out.print(n);
}
if (n == input) {
    System.out.print(" is a prime number.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you play with it a little more you'll find an answer, but here you go:
I would write a method
`public static boolean isPrime(int n)`
and then:

```
if (isPrime(n)) {
        System.out.print(bla bla bla...);
} else {
    print here factors
}
```

Another option (which is a little ugly) is to "remember" if you found a factor:
note the `boolean foundFactor` and its usages:

```
public static void primeFactors(int n) {
boolean foundFactor = false;
while (n % 2 == 0) {
    foundFactor = true
    System.out.print(2 + " ");
    n = n/2;
}

for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i = i+2) {
    while (n % i == 0) {
    foundFactor = true
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        n = n/i;
    }
}

if (n > 2 && !foundFactor) {
    System.out.print(n + " is a prime number.");
}
```

}

Comment: I did try that earlier actually, i made it looking like this (look at my comment below)

Answer (score 0):

I did try creating a method to check if the number is a prime. Looked like this:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {

if (n <= 1) {
  return false;
}

for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
  if (n % i == 0) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

But this also printed the sentence in the end.. :/